# Determinant of Adjacency Matrix is null

Tags: graph-theory, matrices, linear-algebra

Let be $D=(V,E)$ . Prove the determinant of its adjacency matrix , $det(A) = 0$ $\iff$ $\exists S \subseteq V $ (nonempty) such that $|v_{ext} \cap S|$ is an even number , $\forall $ v $\in V$ . $v_{ext}$ denotes the nodes $u$ such that $vu \in E$.
Also , D may have loops (i.e $\exists$ $A_{uu} =1$). All operations are made in $GF(2)$.

I have tried the direct implication in this way : if $det(A) = 0$ , it means that the vectors of $A$ are not linearly independents. But what`s the next step ?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a question of pure mathematics. What insight do you expect computer scientists to have on this question that a mathematician wouldn't have?

Comment: As David Richerby says, this looks like a pure math question.  While we don't have an absolute policy against pure math questions, we do expect that if they're asked here they should have a good reason why they need to be answered from a computer science perspective and should explain in the question what that is, and I'm not seeing any of that here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints:

1. The determinant is $0$, so there is some vector $\mathbf{x}$ with $A \mathbf{x} = 0$.
2. Since all of your calculations are done $\bmod{2}$, your vector $\mathbf{x}$ can be assumed to be a $0/1$ vector.
3. Again, since your calculations are done $\bmod{2}$, $A \mathbf{x} = 0$ means that, if you multiply $A$ times this vector using integers (all numbers in the matrix and vector are either $0$ or $1$), you will get an even number.
4. Since $\mathbf{x}$ contains $0$ and $1$s, and has the same number of entries as your graph has vertices, you can consider a relation ship between $\mathbf{x}$ and a subset $S \subset V$ by interpreting your $0$s and $1$s in a certain way.
5. The entries of $A \mathbf{x}$ are the products of the rows of $A$ with $\mathbf{x}$; the rows of $A$ are each associated with a vertex $v \in V$ in a natural way.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: The determinant of $A$ vanishes iff there is a non-zero vector $x$ such that $Ax=0$.

Comment: Ok , but who is this vector $x$ and how could this helps me in proving that $\exists S \subseteq V $ such that $|v_{ext} \cap S|$ is an even number , $\forall $ v $\in V$

Comment: @penguina That's for you to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another hint: consider the special case $S=\emptyset$.

Comment: Doesn't $S = \emptyset$ provide a counterexample to the claim (when paired with a nonsingular $A$)? My guess was that $S = \emptyset$ needed to be excluded in the statement.